# We're getting an error when users are trying to sign up and create new accounts/ albums using AWS. See terminal message below

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

[AWS s3 undefined 0.006s 0 retries] headObject({ Bucket: 'mypicturebank', Key: 'testing' })
There was an error creating your album: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type undefined

Answer (score 1):

[@Ken G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9347191/ken-g) I'm not sure what language or framework you are using, though I ran across the similar error message `The "key" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type undefined` just now.

In my case and for anyone else who stumbles across this, it was because I was providing the [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) AWS credentials which are returned from AWS [STS.assumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html), where I needed to provide [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) AWS credentials keys:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

# Bad
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  credentials: {
    AccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    SecretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  },
  ...
})

# Good
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  },
  ...
})
```

I am using the [aws-sdk for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) on macOS with Node v10.16.2, with the goal of using [s3.createPresignedPost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property).

Possibly related, on an AWS Lambda instance running node 10.x I was seeing a different error message for the same code: `Key must be a buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be also caused by the reason if you using some env variable in your code and it doesn't exist in the env file or is undefined in it like I was using file stack api so shared key required which is actually missing in the env file.